# What are the requirements for the next parameter for the add tab dialog?

Tags: facebook, dialog, tabs

It is not very clear as to what rules the `next` parameter need to follow in order to be valid with the **add tab dialog**.

I wish the documentation was more clear. As through trial and error I have worked out enough for just now but I want to know if you need to setup the apps as website apps or if you need the domain setup, which requires being setup as a website app. Also it appears you can specify a subdomain with no issues?

It's just not clear at all.

Can we please have clearer documentation? I realise I maybe posting this in the wrong place as well, so if this should be filed somewhere else can someone please let me know.

Thanks!

Stefan

Answer (score 1):

Next is the url where you are redirect after you have added the tab

example:
next="https://www.yourdomain.com/add_tab.php"